# How Can I Prevent a Race Condition on Server Restart when Running Multiple Payara Domains?

Tags: race-condition, payara

I am trying to run 4 Payara domains per Windows 2019 server (I also have a few running on 2016). I can only use Payara 5.1.9.1 or 5.1.9.4 right now as those are the two supported for the two versions of this particular application I am hosting. I just have one application deployed per domain.

The Payara domains are configured as Windows Services set to run as Network Service. I have the two production domains set to start immediately and the two test domains set to start using "Delayed Start" in the windows service start up options.

In this environment, the servers are scheduled to run windows updates automatically every Sunday and do a reboot if necessary around 3am. My problem is that when the servers reboot for Updates, perhaps only one or two domains on each server will come up. Prior to setting the two test domains to delayed start up, often-times none of the domains would come up. Or just 1/4 would come up.

Each server has two cores and 12 GB RAM. These are the recs I got from PD so I admit I am not sure if it's enough, I am just using what they said. The CPU pegs during starting the domains, but seems OK just when running the applications. Even if I am just starting one domain at a time, it will still spike / peg, but not as badly if I try to start 2 or more very close together.

The Windows Service error is this:

`Child process [4120 - D:/.../payara/194/payara5/glassfish/lib/nadmin.bat  start-domain --watchdog --domaindir D:\...\payara\domains (domain name) ] terminated with 1`

The Payara domain server log entries go like this:

`[2020-06-21T03:47:48.866-0700] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00014] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592736468866] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payara Microprofile Config needs running server environment to work. Either it's not running, or you're experiencing a race condition
at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.await(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:55)
at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.getConfig(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:77)
at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:119)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]`

`[2020-06-21T03:47:48.866-0700] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592736468866] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Failed to start, exiting]]`

`[2020-06-21T03:47:48.866-0700] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592736468866] [levelValue: 800] [[
FileMonitoring shutdown]]`

`[2020-06-21T03:47:48.898-0700] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=195 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592736468882] [timeMillis: 1592736468898] [levelValue: 800] [[
JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]]]`

`[2020-06-21T03:47:48.913-0700] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=196 _ThreadName=Thread-21] [timeMillis: 1592736468913] [levelValue: 800] [[
RAR7094: __ds_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.]]`

So it seems like even just trying to start two domains simultaneously is too much. I fully admit to being new to Payara so maybe I am asking why water is wet but... Why can't I just have them all start up when the server reboots? Is there a config option I need inside the domains to get them to play nicely? Is running four Payara domains on a single server a bad idea?

Why does each Payara domain take so long to come up? It can take up to 10 minutes for all four of these domains to come up and the applications to load, and sometimes it takes another minute or two after that for all the components that actually allow me to log in to the application, to load. On another similar server, using Payara 5.1.7.1 for a different application, it takes literally 15 minutes from rebooting the server to having all the domains come up and the applications to load (just 3 domains on that server).

Am I just dramatically under-powered for what I'm trying to do? Am I trying to do something that it's just not designed for? Am I just missing something obvious in the config?

edit >>>

without any applications deployed in the domains, and all 4 services set to automatic (no delay), when I restart the server, I still get one domain that doesn't come up. Here's the error from that. I'm going to do a few more reboots and see if it consistently does this.

`[2020-06-21T17:35:20.612-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00016] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310830] [timeMillis: 1592775320612] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Startup service failed to start
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payara Microprofile Config needs running server environment to work. Either it's not running, or you're experiencing a race condition
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.await(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:55)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.getConfig(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:20.952-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775320952] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId=[100]]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:21.633-0400] [Payara 5.194] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775321633] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to construct HTTP/2 Addon
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/grizzly/npn/AlpnServerNegotiator
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configureHttp2Support(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:806)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configureHttpProtocol(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:782)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.configureHttpProtocol(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configureSubProtocol(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configureProtocol(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configure(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.initialize(GrizzlyProxy.java:126)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:664)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:586)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.grizzly.npn.AlpnServerNegotiator
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:1179)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1618)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1548)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 23 more
]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:22.408-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775322408] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener http-listener-1 started in: 732ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:21080]]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:22.409-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00058] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775322409] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network listener http-listener-2 on port 21081 disabled per domain.xml]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:22.426-0400] [Payara 5.194] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775322426] [levelValue: 900] [[
  HTTP/2 (enabled by default) is unsupported with port unification and will be disabled for network listener admin-listener.]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:23.631-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775323631] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener admin-listener started in: 1,194ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:21048]]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:23.633-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1592775310829] [timeMillis: 1592775323633] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly 2.4.3 started in: 8,174ms - bound to [http-listener-1:21080, admin-listener:21048]]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:24.106-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00014] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592775324106] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payara Microprofile Config needs running server environment to work. Either it's not running, or you're experiencing a race condition
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.await(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:55)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.getConfig(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:24.110-0400] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592775324110] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Failed to start, exiting]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:24.118-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592775324118] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:24.564-0400] [Payara 5.194] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1592775324564] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.16.Final]]

[2020-06-21T17:35:26.944-0400] [Payara 5.194] [WARNING] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1592775326944] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Timeout out waiting for Microprofile Config startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payara Microprofile Config needs running server environment to work. Either it's not running, or you're experiencing a race condition
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.await(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:55)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.getConfig(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics.MetricID.<init>(MetricID.java:121)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.metrics.impl.MetricRegistryImpl.register(MetricRegistryImpl.java:314)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.metrics.jmx.MBeanMetadataHelper.registerMetadata(MBeanMetadataHelper.java:118)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.metrics.MetricsService.initMetadataConfig(MetricsService.java:241)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.metrics.MetricsService.bootstrap(MetricsService.java:453)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.metrics.MetricsService.lambda$init$0(MetricsService.java:144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]`

Comment: Re startup time: Payara itself starts within seconds on a fresh domain. So maybe the application takes long to deploy? Deployment times in that magnitude could also be the result of a network timeout, e.g. DNS lookup.

Comment: Well so I watch it as it's starting to see when I can access the admin console as compared to when I access the application. Maybe that's not a good test but I'm still trying to learn. Payara itself takes a while to come up on these servers, and then another few minutes for the application to load.

Comment: A log file from the startup without any applications deployed would be helpful. On the other hand I just realize that this is actually not your question. ;)

Comment: It's true it's not precisely my question but it's still related. I need to understand this stuff better so it's all good in my book. I'll try it without any applications deployed and see how quickly just the domains by themselves load.

Comment: I added the log from starting up with no applications.

Comment: The `ClassNotFoundException` for the `AlpnServerNegotiator` seems to be a known bug. Please see the following on how to prevent it: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3138 and https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3967

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem, in my case I had to remove the Hotswap libs to be able to run the server again, it just stopped working from one day to the next.
I also noticed changes in `domain.xml` that I didn't do.

```
<context-service object-type="system-all" jndi-name="concurrent/__defaultContextService"></context-service>
<managed-thread-factory object-type="system-all" jndi-name="concurrent/__defaultManagedThreadFactory"></managed-thread-factory>

<resource-ref ref="concurrent/__defaultContextService"></resource-ref>
<resource-ref ref="concurrent/__defaultManagedThreadFactory"></resource-ref>

<microprofile-openapi-configuration></microprofile-openapi-configuration>
<ejb-container>
  <ejb-timer-service></ejb-timer-service>
</ejb-container>
<rest-config></rest-config>
<environment-warning-configuration></environment-warning-configuration>
<cdi-service></cdi-service>
<jdbc-config-source-configuration></jdbc-config-source-configuration>
```

I have 2 Payaras (4.1.2 and 5.2021), both throw the same error